# Can I rip DVDs from a local web app with HandBrake?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm building a PHP web application that will run on my machine, and one of its purposes is to call HandBrakeCLI with an exec() or similar call. If I run the command

```
HandBrakeCLI -i path_to_dvd_drive -o output_file --preset preset_name
```

from a shell, it works fine. However, when I put the exact same command in an exec() php function (or similar), it doesn't work, and doesn't return anything, aside from a return status of 0. No errors, nothing else.

Is this just a simple permissions issue that I'm not seeing, due to the lack of errors being spit out? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging, try running the command from the console but as the user PHP runs as. [Here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/599800) are some pointers how to find out which user that is.

Then use [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) to run the command as the Apache user. You will probably get more helpful information from that.

Comment: Perfect! That helped. Turns out the error was insufficient access to the DVD drive. I can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

try to exec your script using absolute path (type `which HandBrakeCLI` in terminal to find it) and append `2>&1` to the end of command, like:

`exec('HandBrakeCLI -i path_to_dvd_drive -o output_file --preset preset_name 2>&1')`

this way if command outputs anything to stderr you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

is handbrake in the path of whatever shell PHP is invoking when it does the exec()? Does whatever account PHP/webserver is running under have access to the directory where handbrak.exe is, and have permission to execute handbrake.exe? Does the webserver account have permissions to access the dvd drive, etc...

Many things to check, and without better diagnostic information, this is about the best you'll be able to get here.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu machine. Stock install of HandBrakeCLI from the Ubuntu Software Center, as well as PHP. I'm kind of hoping I can at least get pointed in the direction of where I can find some logging of the issue that prevents it from running.